# Differentiation of $(1 + \tan x)/(1 - \tan x)$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

While practicing differentiation, I got stuck at the following question:

Prove that,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac {1 + \tan x}{1 - \tan x} = \frac{2\cos x}{(1 - \sin x)^2} $$

I worked upon it to obtain the following result,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac {1 + \tan x}{1 - \tan x} = \frac{2\sec^2 x}{(1 - \tan x)^2} $$

Can anyone please help me prove the question?

Comment: Your first formula is not true. What is the source of the problem?

Comment: This is quotient rule, just do it.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{{2\sec ^2 x}}{{(1 - \tan x)^2 }} = \frac{2}{{\cos ^2 x(1 - \tan x)^2 }} = \frac{2}{{(\cos x - \sin x)^2 }} = \frac{2}{{\cos ^2 x - 2\sin x\cos x + \sin ^2 x}} = \frac{2}{{1 - \sin (2x)}}.$$

Comment: I got my answer using Quotient Rule only! What i am unable to do is to prove the question as asked.

Comment: @KaushalDoshi, you can't prove because it's not true... I ask again, what is the source of the question?

Comment: @Atticus I too think the problem is in the question.

Comment: @Atticus, The source happens to be a book from local publisher.

Comment: Thank you @Atticus

Comment: Thank you @Gary.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat too for your time.

Comment: Maybe they meant $2/(\cos x-\sin x)^2$.  At least that works.

Comment: Thank you @Oscar Lanzi

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)}=-\frac{1-\tan(x)-2}{1-\tan(x)}=\frac{2}{1-\tan(x)}-1$$

Comment: thank you for the hint. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Note,

$$\frac{2\cos x}{(1 - \sin x)^2} \ne \frac{2\sec^2 x}{(1 - \tan x)^2} $$

which is evident with $x=\pi$, i.e.

$$\frac{2\cdot (-1)}{(1 - 0)^2} \ne \frac{2\cdot 1 }{(1 - 0)^2} $$

Comment: Thank you @Quanto

Answer (score 2):

You mean to check/confirm your result. Just apply Chain Rule and simplify

$$\frac{c+s}{c-s}\rightarrow \frac{ (c-s)(-s+c)-(c+s)(-s-c)}{(c-s)^2}  $$

$$= \frac{(c-s)^2 +(c+s)^2 }{(c-s)^2} = \frac{2}{(c-s)^2} $$

which agrees with your result.

Comment: Thank you @Narasimham

Comment: If it is misprint can ask publisher to correct error.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the quotient rule,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}&=\frac{(1-\tan x)\frac{\mathrm d(1+\tan x)}{\mathrm dx}-(1+\tan x)\frac{\mathrm d(1-\tan x)}{\mathrm dx}}{(1-\tan x)^2}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{(1-\tan x)\sec^2x-(1+\tan x)(-\sec^2x)}{(1-\tan x)^2}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{2\sec^2x}{(1-\tan x)^2}\\[1ex]
\end{align*}$$

To write this in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, since $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, you can multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2x$ to arrive at

$$\frac{2\sec^2x\cos^2x}{(1-\tan x)^2\cos^2x}=\frac2{(\cos x-\cos x\tan x)^2}=\frac2{(\cos x-\sin x)^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for you time. I already have these results. What i needed help in proving was the form, $$ \frac{2\cos x}{(1 - \sin x)^2}, $$ which, according to @Atticus too, appears to be completely false.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

$g(x) = {1+x \over 1-x}$ so $g'(x) = {2 \over (1-x)^2}$ and $f = g \circ \tan$ so
$f'(x) = g(\tan x) \tan' x = {2 \over (1 - \tan x )^2} {1 \over \cos^2 x} = {2 \over (1 - {\sin x \over \cos x} )^2} {1 \over \cos^2 x} = {2 \over (\cos x -\sin x)^2}$.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat

Comment: Why the downvote? Something wrong? Please explain otherwise it is annoyance without value.

Comment: i did not downvote. i do not downvote. If found proper, i upvote. I am not here to annoy. Nor am I here to get annoyed.